# How to show taxonomy on front page

Tags: taxonomy, redirect, homepage, frontpage

I have set template `taxonomy-event_type.php` which displays just right on `http://localhost:8000/types/<type_name>/`.

What I need now is to:

- either redirect when user lands on `http://localhost:8000` to this page,
- or use this template with (what wouldn't be greatest, as i'm checking the url and setting navigation items as active according to the url)

So something like (PSEUDOCODE):

```
if is_home(): 
   redirect('types/type1')
```

or

```
use_template('taxonomy-event_type','type1');
```

is it possible?

Comment: Note that the template doesn't determine the posts that get shown, so if you did load that template on the homepage, it would be the same posts you saw on the homepage before but in that template, not the posts from a particular term. URL creates query -> query fetches posts -> query + posts determines template to load

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
// redirect on homepage to taxonomy
add_action("template_redirect", function() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        return wp_redirect(get_term_link('type1', 'event_type'));
    }
});
```